# How to collapse a collection into one and sum specific keys

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have following  collection:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:21 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "referrer" => "Kariane Muller DVM"
    "path" => null
    "tracking_code_id" => 30
    "sales" => 2
    "field_name" => "ssn"
    "income" => 4.0
    "fsId" => "1b5e4434-da5a-342e-9b87-df9791b1bcc1"
  ]
  2 => array:21 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "referrer" => "Kariane Muller DVM"
    "path" => null
    "tracking_code_id" => 30
    "sales" => 1
    "field_name" => "income"
    "income" => 1.0
    "fsId" => "1b5e4434-da5a-342e-9b87-df9791b1bcc1"
  ]
```

For visibility purposes I have converted it to array.

How can I collapse this collection into one collection, but I want to 
`sum` the `income` keys into one in final collection.

Other keys should be included as they are ?

Comment: Probably easier to approach this from the other direction. Rather than merging the collection, perhaps make sure the collection is pulling the correct properties from the source?

Comment: @jakeharris that was my issue database layer was returning faulty data. But I got it fixed on database level instead

Answer (score 0):

I would start with reduce. If I am understanding correctly you basically want the original collection intact but the income to be summed and reflected in every item.

```
$summedIncome = $collection->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
    $income = $carry->has('income') ? ($item->income + $carry->income) : $item->income;
    $carry->push($item);
    $carry->each->income = $income;
    return $carry;
}, collect([]));
```

Comment: nah does not really work, but thanks for the time. I did it on database level instead